# If $x_n$ is a sequence of positive numbers such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ $(x_n)^{1/n} = L < 1$, show $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I've been playing around with numbers for the past hour and deduced that if $x_n$ is a sequence such as $(1/2)^n$ the statement holds. However, I'm not sure if there are other types of sequences that work this way or how to even prove this generally. I stumbled across using the Root Test since it is a strictly positive sequence. However, I don't think my teacher wants me to use that yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pick $M$ with $L<M<1$. Then for all large enough $n$ we have $0<x_n^{1/n}< M$, i.e., $0<x_n<M^n\to 0$.